# add regex in url in django

Tags: python-3.x, django, regex, url, path

I have a url link in my template django   like this

```
http://localhost/ville/selectville/name/?&name=Paris+-+75002
```

I need to remove all characters that are before the character "+" to have a url like this

```
http://localhost/ville/selectville/name/?&name=Paris
```

this regex  do the job

```
myurl = "http://localhost/city/selectville/name/?&name=Paris+-+75002"
re.sub(r'\+.*', '', myurl )
```

but how to integrate it in my urls.py file with this path

```
path('selectville/<str:name>/', VilleSelect.as_view(), name='ville_select'),
```

thank you

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a big question:

1. To just get the portion of the url you're looking to get, you would use a Django template filter. This way, you can insert the url into your template and the filter can use python (i.e. the re.sub) to re-add the url
2. The urls.py looks perfectly fine to me. Let's assume this is your view:

```py
def view(request, name: str):
    ...
```

`name` is actually just "name". The `name=Paris` portion is can be accessed via `request.GET.get("name") == "Paris"`. The re.sub portion, assuming you implement the Django filter, would not be included.

Comment: thank acw, I will look into your solutions